# Do I have this equivalency for data.table and ddply right?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Example: filtering a signal or series (same number of output rows as input)

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
dummy.table <- data.table(val=runif(30),group1=rep(1:2,times=15),group2 = rep(1:15,each=2))


library(signal)
end.f <- 20
start.f <- 10
sample.rate <- 256
low.pass <- butter(buttord(Wp = start.f/sample.rate*2,
                       Ws = end.f/sample.rate*2,
                       Rp = 0.5, Rs = 40))
```

Given the above data, how can I fix the `ddply` call? Whether I use `summarize` or `mutate`, the number of rows output is not the same.

```
dummy.table[,val:=filtfilt(low.pass,val), by=c("group1","group2")]

filt.test <- ddply(dummy.table, .(group1, group2),
               mutate,
               val=filtfilt(filt=low.pass,x=dummy.table$val))
```

Comment: Are you sure that `dummy.table.filt` will exist? I know hadley does some wierd stuff with evaluation mechanisms but I suspect you dragged in some language conventions from some other OOP language.

Comment: In general, `mutate` should not change the number of rows.

Comment: @BondedDust sorry, that was a code typo from making the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not saying whether you were getting error. The `dummy.table.file$` looked both wrong and I thought ddply would probably make `val` available in the evaluation environment. This runs without error.:

```
 filt.test <- ddply(dummy.table, .(group1, group2),
                mutate,
                val=filtfilt(filt=low.pass,x=val))
#--------------
 str(filt.test)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ val   : num  0.000239 0.000425 0.000416 0.000402 0.000225 ...
 $ group1: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I was wondering if it might be better to use `summarise` instead of `mutate`, but it looks like I get the same result. I also suspect you are not getting data.table efficiency. That might be improved with the `dplyr` package, though.

Comment: Where do you think the issue is with the data.table call? The filtering functions are direct ports from Octave unfortunately (according to the docs) so they might not be optimized.